# How can I use .NOTPARALLEL in makefile only on specific targets?

Tags: linux, makefile

I have 5 labels in Makefile:

```
all: label1 label2 label3 label4 last_label
```

I want `last_label` to be done last, and I want to use `make -j`. If I use `.NOTPARALLEL`, it will make all of them `NOTPARALLEL`, any suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: I edited the title to reflect that it was a ["XY problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). 
The answers to the X problem of this question are just right.
The answer to the "XY" question is "You can't", because with `.NOTPARALLEL` [all targets will run serially](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a target specifying the four targets that can be executed in parallel & include this and `last_label` in the `all` target:

```
intermediate: label1 label2 label3 label4

all:
        $(MAKE) intermediate
        $(MAKE) last_label
```

This would execute the targets specified within `intermediate` in parallel, but `intermediate` and `last_label` would be forced consecutively.

(Note that the leading space before `$(MAKE)` is a `TAB` character.)

Comment: Yes.  The solution would work in parallel, regardless of the number of simultaneous jobs.

Comment: I assume the `intermediate` target should come after `all`, otherwise it would become the default target.

Answer (score 15):

If the reason `last_label` needs to run last is that it needs data from the other labels, the best approach would be to tell `make` about that dependency:

```
all: last_label

last_label: label1 label2 label3 label4
```

If there's not a true dependency (i.e., if you don't want `last_label` to be rebuilt if one of the others changes), and if you're using GNU Make, you can specify these as "order-only" dependencies--`make` will just make sure they exist before `last_label` is built:

```
all: last_label

last_label: | label1 label2 label3 label4
```

Comment: It is called [order-only dependency](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-order_002donly-prerequisites-145) to be precise.

Comment: this should solve the base requirement - hence the make even if it forks many processes it will have to ensure that order of completion of the targets even iff the non parallel option is not used !!  , +1 @laindir

Comment: this will not work with -j7 , since it ignore everything i think

Comment: This will work with any number of jobs, since we have explicitly told `make` that last_label must not run before the other labels have finished.