# Best practices to avoid race conditions in a makefile?

Tags: build, compilation, makefile

Do you know some way to avoid race conditions when you write a makefile that should be run in parallel? There is some kind of barriers? How can I run sequentially some part? or, How can I pause the other processors until some critical object is created?

Thanks!

Comment: Make is supposed to take care of that itself *unless* you use recursive make in which case you have broken the guarantee. If you haven't read it search for "Recursive Make Considered Harmful".

Comment: Note that make itself (GNU make, anyway) is single-threaded and so can never (barring recursion errors as dmckee says) have a race condition.  The way it achieves parallelism is by running multiple commands in the background at the same time.  So as long as your commands don't interact with each other while writing, you won't have issues with race conditions.  If you have a specific problem, please describe it.

Comment: Looks like you're using `-j`.  Check if http://stackoverflow.com/a/16831451/2235132 helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things you need to consider:

1. Don't generate files which are not specified as a target. For instance if you have 2 rules that coincidentally produce "fred.tmp" (and maybe even delete it afterwards), and they both run at the same time, bad things will happen
2. Keep your build rules as short as possible. Preferably one command.
3. Don't do recursive builds. Even if they don't break, the -j gets passed to each child make, resulting in an exponential rise in CPU usage.

There is no way in standard make to indicate 2 rules cannot be run in parallel.

You may wish to consider investigating some other build tools as well (such as [SCons](http://www.scons.org)) to see if they solve your problem better.