# How can I use .NOTPARALLEL in makefile only on targets from list?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I use `make` to perform a complicated computation which involves several runs of different programs, whose calculation results depend on each other. Among that runs there are several executions of highly optimized/vectorized/multi-threaded program and several executions of single threaded python scripts. So `Makefile` have this part:

```
slow_target/%: fast_target/%
   python $<
   #run of the unparalleled single-threaded python program

fast_target/%: #some dependencies for each %
   #run of the multi-core paralleled program
```

`fast_target/%` can be stored in variable, but can not be enumerated by hand (there are dozens of them).

I want to compute all `fast_target/%` sequentially but other targets in parallel. How to do it?

P.S. This question is a bit similar to [How can I use .NOTPARALLEL in makefile only on specific targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829933/how-can-i-use-notparallel-in-makefile-only-on-specific-targets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to use a synchronization on a file level within the recipe. It's not of course the best (as it will still consume `make`'s job), but should not overload the system by running *n* multiple-threaded programs.

Sample Makefile:

```
$ cat Makefile
all: $(foreach number,1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10,$(addsuffix /$(number),slow_target fast_target))

slow_target/%:
        @echo $@
        @python3 -c 'import time; time.sleep(5)'

fast_target/%:
        @( \
          flock 9 || exit 1; \
          echo $@; \
          python3 -c 'import time; time.sleep(5)' \
        ) 9> fast_target.lock
```

Output:

```
$ make -j8 | ts
May 19 23:45:06 slow_target/1
May 19 23:45:06 slow_target/2
May 19 23:45:06 fast_target/1
May 19 23:45:06 slow_target/3
May 19 23:45:06 slow_target/4
May 19 23:45:11 fast_target/2
May 19 23:45:11 slow_target/5
May 19 23:45:11 slow_target/6
May 19 23:45:11 slow_target/7
May 19 23:45:16 fast_target/3
May 19 23:45:16 slow_target/8
May 19 23:45:16 slow_target/9
May 19 23:45:21 fast_target/4
May 19 23:45:21 slow_target/10
May 19 23:45:26 fast_target/5
May 19 23:45:31 fast_target/6
May 19 23:45:36 fast_target/7
May 19 23:45:41 fast_target/8
May 19 23:45:46 fast_target/9
May 19 23:45:51 fast_target/10
```

Note that *slow_targets* are started in parallel, but only one *fast_target* at a time is started.

**EDIT**

`flock` acquires a lock on a given file or a given file descriptor. The lock by default is exclusive, meaning that only one `flock` call can continue and all others will block until the lock is released. Therefore if multiple targets are invoked in parallel, only one `flock` will proceed, while others will wait till the lock is released.

The statement in the recipe is based on `flock`'s manual. It opens up file descriptor 9 on a `fast_target.lock` file for a given block. At the beginning `flock` acquires an exclusive lock on this descriptor (thus `fast_target.lock` file), which will automatically be released when the descriptor is closed (that is when the block with redirection ends). When that happens, one of other `flock`s will proceed, effectively allowing only one `fast_target` recipe execution.

**EDIT 2**

If all *fast_targets* are known and always executed, they can be dynamically scheduled in a sequence, like so:

```
$ cat Makefile2
SLOW_TARGETS := $(addprefix slow_target/,1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
FAST_TARGETS := $(addprefix fast_target/,1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)

all: $(SLOW_TARGETS) $(FAST_TARGETS)

slow_target/%:
        @echo $@
        @python3 -c 'import time; time.sleep(5)'

fast_target/%:
        @echo $@: $^
        @python3 -c 'import time; time.sleep(5)'

$(foreach target,$(FAST_TARGETS), \
  $(eval evaluated_targets += $(target)) \
  $(eval next_target := $(word 2,$(wordlist $(words $(evaluated_targets)),$(words $(FAST_TARGETS)),$(FAST_TARGETS)))) \
  $(eval $(if $(next_target),$(next_target): $(target))) \
)
```

This will iterate the list of known *fast_targets* and for every target it will define a dependency to the previous one. This will result in a strict sequence to run, so none of them will be run in parallel. Additionally it will not block `make` jobs, so the executors will be available for other targets instead of being blocked on the `flock`.

```
$ make -f Makefile2 -j8 | ts
May 20 22:38:35 slow_target/1
May 20 22:38:35 slow_target/2
May 20 22:38:35 slow_target/3
May 20 22:38:35 slow_target/4
May 20 22:38:35 slow_target/5
May 20 22:38:35 slow_target/6
May 20 22:38:35 slow_target/7
May 20 22:38:35 slow_target/8
May 20 22:38:40 slow_target/9
May 20 22:38:40 slow_target/10
May 20 22:38:40 fast_target/1:
May 20 22:38:45 fast_target/2: fast_target/1
May 20 22:38:51 fast_target/3: fast_target/2
May 20 22:38:56 fast_target/4: fast_target/3
May 20 22:39:01 fast_target/5: fast_target/4
May 20 22:39:06 fast_target/6: fast_target/5
May 20 22:39:11 fast_target/7: fast_target/6
May 20 22:39:16 fast_target/8: fast_target/7
May 20 22:39:21 fast_target/9: fast_target/8
May 20 22:39:26 fast_target/10: fast_target/9
```

Note that due to dependency, it is not possible to run e.g. only `fast_target/10` without further logic manipulation, as all previous targets will also be run. This would not be the case with the `flock` approach.

Comment: Can you explain the "flock" part a bit. I've understood the idea, but I'm not familiar with `flock` syntax. Are `9` and `9>` connected?

Comment: @mehalom Yes, they are. I've updated the response in hope to be more clear.